# Can I specify the nonce and counter in AES encryption counter mode?

Tags: encryption, aes, crypto++

I'm trying to use the library Crypto++ to make AES Counter mode based encryption/decryption

I want to split the IV value into nonce and counter.
Is there any API that directly takes the nonce and counter to construct the IV ?

I did the following to achieve it

```
byte counter[AES::BLOCKSIZE/2] = {0x0};     // initialized to zero : 64 bit counter
string counterstr ;
byte nonce[AES::BLOCKSIZE/2];                // 64 bit nonce 
string noncestr ;
prng.GenerateBlock(nonce, sizeof(nonce));
StringSource(nonce, sizeof(nonce), true,
    new HexEncoder(
    new StringSink(noncestr)
    ) // HexEncoder
    );
StringSource(counter, sizeof(counter), true,
    new HexEncoder(
    new StringSink(counterstr)
    ) // HexEncoder
    );
SecByteBlock no = HexDecodeString(noncestr);
SecByteBlock ctr = HexDecodeString(counterstr);
string ivv = noncestr + counterstr;
SecByteBlock ivvb = HexDecodeString(ivv);
```

then I use

```
e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);
```

#### Questions:

- Is this the only way to achieve this or is there any other easier way?
- Does the counter value increment automatically when doing encryption or decryption of  blocks?
- This one is trivial, should I specify another nonce value for each block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the only way to achieve this or is there any other easier way?

No. The increment function operates on the full 128-bit block. See [CTR mode and Counter Increment](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CTR_Mode) on the Crypto++ wiki.

The longer answer is Yes ***if*** you provide your own `IncrementCounter` function. The longer answer can be Yes ***if*** you use the high order bits for the nonce and low order bits for the counter (see more below).

---

> Does the counter value increment automatically when doing encryption or decryption of blocks?

Yes.

---

> This one is trivial, should I specify another nonce value for each block?

No. The counter is incremented.

---

> Is there any API that directly takes the nonce and counter to construct the IV ?

No. In more practical terms, there is a limit to how much plain text can be encrypted under a key/nonce pair (or security context). I think its well below 2 GB. If my recollection is correct, then you will have to re-key long before your counter gets into the high 64-bits.

In effect, that means you can use the high 64-bits as the random nonce, and use the lower 64-bits as the counter. So your code would look something like:

```
byte counter[AES::BLOCKSIZE] = {0};
prng.GenerateBlock(counter, 8);
```

After the code above executes, the high 64-bits will be random, and the low 64-bits will start at 0 and serve as the counter.

Since 2 GB is about the limit, you can use a 12-4 split rather than a 8-8 split:

```
byte counter[AES::BLOCKSIZE] = {0};
prng.GenerateBlock(counter, 12);
```

After the code above executes, the high 96-bits will be random, and the low 32-bits will start at 0 and serve as the counter.

---

Related, never reuse a nonce. Each message must have its own, unique security context. That usually means a unique nonce (the other option is to provide a unique key for each message). Otherwise, you can trivially recover the key with an `XOR`.

Comment: `counter values * block size = 2^64 * 16 bytes` would be much more than 2GB of data for one nonce-key pair. Using 64-bit for the counter is a little wasteful. When a counter of 32-bit is used then 64 GiB can be safely encrypted under the same nonce-key pair. This would also make generating the nonce randomly a little more resilient against nonce-reuse since it is now 96-bit wide.

Comment: How did you calculate the 2GB value?

Comment: @Artjom - I did not calculate the 2 GB value. I'm working from memory, which may be wrong. Section 3 of [Counter Mode Security:
Analysis and Recommendations](http://www.mindspring.com/~dmcgrew/ctr-security.pdf) provides a limit based on risk tolerance.